# Editing specific line in text file in Python

Tags: python, io

Let's say I have a text file containing:

```
Dan
Warrior
500
1
0
```

Is there a way I can edit a specific line in that text file? Right now I have this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import io

myfile = open('stats.txt', 'r')
dan = myfile.readline()
print dan
print "Your name: " + dan.split('\n')[0]

try:
    myfile = open('stats.txt', 'a')
    myfile.writelines('Mage')[1]
except IOError:
        myfile.close()
finally:
        myfile.close()
```

Yes, I know that `myfile.writelines('Mage')[1]` is incorrect. But you get my point, right? I'm trying to edit line 2 by replacing Warrior with Mage. But can I even do that?

Comment: If you have to do this sort of thing a lot, you might want to look into converting this file from text to something like bdb or other bdb-alike.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

You want to do something like this:

```
# with is like your try .. finally block in this case
with open('stats.txt', 'r') as file:
    # read a list of lines into data
    data = file.readlines()

print data
print "Your name: " + data[0]

# now change the 2nd line, note that you have to add a newline
data[1] = 'Mage\n'

# and write everything back
with open('stats.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines( data )
```

The reason for this is that you can't do something like "change line 2" directly in a file. You can only overwrite (not delete) parts of a file - that means that the new content just covers the old content. So, if you wrote 'Mage' over line 2, the resulting line would be 'Mageior'.

Comment: Hi Jochen, the statement "with open(filename, mode)" also closes filename implicitly after program exits it, right?

Comment: @Gabriel Thx, that is important to note, although I still don't use the with ... as file statement. Pythonic or not, I don't like it :)

Comment: @Radu it's a matter of getting used to it. I also used to close opened files manually via `close.` but now I see that using a `with` block is much cleaner.

Comment: Is it correct to assume, this is a solution preferred for small files? Otherwise we might need a lot of memory just to store the data. Moreover, even for 1 edit, we need to write the whole thing again.

Comment: Bad.. what if you have 20 Gb file?

Answer (score 38):

```
def replace_line(file_name, line_num, text):
    lines = open(file_name, 'r').readlines()
    lines[line_num] = text
    out = open(file_name, 'w')
    out.writelines(lines)
    out.close()
```

And then:

```
replace_line('stats.txt', 0, 'Mage')
```

Comment: this would load the entire file's content into memory which might not be a good thing if the file is huge.

Comment: @SteveNg do you have a solution for the problem you noticed ? both this answer and the accepted one rely on loading the entire file in memory

Answer (score 28):

You can use `fileinput` to do in-place editing

```py
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("myfile", inplace=1):
    if line .....: # select which lines you care about
        print line
```

Comment: Note, though, that this rewrites the entire file behind the scenes. A file does not permit random access; there is no way to change something in the middle and not modify the rest.

Answer (score 17):

You can do it in two ways, choose what suits your requirement:

**Method I.)** Replacing using line number. You can use built-in function `enumerate()` in this case:

First, in **read mode** get all data in a variable

```
with open("your_file.txt",'r') as f:
    get_all=f.readlines()
```

Second, write to the file (where **enumerate** comes to action)

```
with open("your_file.txt",'w') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         ## STARTS THE NUMBERING FROM 1 (by default it begins with 0)    
        if i == 2:                              ## OVERWRITES line:2
            f.writelines("Mage\n")
        else:
            f.writelines(line)
```

**Method II.)** Using the keyword you want to replace:

Open file in *read mode* and copy the contents to a list

```
with open("some_file.txt","r") as f:
    newline=[]
    for word in f.readlines():        
        newline.append(word.replace("Warrior","Mage"))  ## Replace the keyword while you copy.
```

"Warrior" has been replaced by "Mage", so write the updated data to the file:

```
with open("some_file.txt","w") as f:
    for line in newline:
        f.writelines(line)
```

This is what the **output** will be in both cases:

```
Dan                   Dan           
Warrior   ------>     Mage       
500                   500           
1                     1   
0                     0
```

Comment: I tried both the methods ; Method (I) didn't work quite well but Method (II) was working fine . Still , they're good to work on .

Answer (score 3):

If your text contains only one individual:

```
import re

# creation
with open('pers.txt','wb') as g:
    g.write('Dan \n Warrior \n 500 \r\n 1 \r 0 ')

with open('pers.txt','rb') as h:
    print 'exact content of pers.txt before treatment:\n',repr(h.read())
with open('pers.txt','rU') as h:
    print '\nrU-display of pers.txt before treatment:\n',h.read()


# treatment
def roplo(file_name,what):
    patR = re.compile('^([^\r\n]+[\r\n]+)[^\r\n]+')
    with open(file_name,'rb+') as f:
        ch = f.read()
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(patR.sub('\\1'+what,ch))
roplo('pers.txt','Mage')


# after treatment
with open('pers.txt','rb') as h:
    print '\nexact content of pers.txt after treatment:\n',repr(h.read())
with open('pers.txt','rU') as h:
    print '\nrU-display of pers.txt after treatment:\n',h.read()
```

If your text contains several individuals:

import re

```
# creation
with open('pers.txt','wb') as g:
    g.write('Dan \n Warrior \n 500 \r\n 1 \r 0 \n Jim  \n  dragonfly\r300\r2\n10\r\nSomo\ncosmonaut\n490\r\n3\r65')

with open('pers.txt','rb') as h:
    print 'exact content of pers.txt before treatment:\n',repr(h.read())
with open('pers.txt','rU') as h:
    print '\nrU-display of pers.txt before treatment:\n',h.read()


# treatment
def ripli(file_name,who,what):
    with open(file_name,'rb+') as f:
        ch = f.read()
        x,y = re.search('^\s*'+who+'\s*[\r\n]+([^\r\n]+)',ch,re.MULTILINE).span(1)
        f.seek(x)
        f.write(what+ch[y:])
ripli('pers.txt','Jim','Wizard')


# after treatment
with open('pers.txt','rb') as h:
    print 'exact content of pers.txt after treatment:\n',repr(h.read())
with open('pers.txt','rU') as h:
    print '\nrU-display of pers.txt after treatment:\n',h.read()
```

If the “job“ of an individual was of a constant length in the texte, you could change only the portion of texte corresponding to the “job“ the desired individual:
that’s the same idea as senderle’s one.

But according to me, better would be to put the characteristics of individuals in a dictionnary recorded in file with cPickle:

```
from cPickle import dump, load

with open('cards','wb') as f:
    dump({'Dan':['Warrior',500,1,0],'Jim':['dragonfly',300,2,10],'Somo':['cosmonaut',490,3,65]},f)

with open('cards','rb') as g:
    id_cards = load(g)
print 'id_cards before change==',id_cards

id_cards['Jim'][0] = 'Wizard'

with open('cards','w') as h:
    dump(id_cards,h)

with open('cards') as e:
    id_cards = load(e)
print '\nid_cards after change==',id_cards
```

Answer (score 2):

I have been practising working on files this evening and realised that I can build on Jochen's answer to provide greater functionality for repeated/multiple use. Unfortunately my answer does not address issue of dealing with large files but does make life easier in smaller files.

```
with open('filetochange.txt', 'r+') as foo:
    data = foo.readlines()                  #reads file as list
    pos = int(input("Which position in list to edit? "))-1  #list position to edit
    data.insert(pos, "more foo"+"\n")           #inserts before item to edit
    x = data[pos+1]
    data.remove(x)                      #removes item to edit
    foo.seek(0)                     #seeks beginning of file
    for i in data:
        i.strip()                   #strips "\n" from list items
        foo.write(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose I have a file named `file_name` as following:

```
this is python
it is file handling
this is editing of line
```

We have to replace line 2 with "modification is done":

```
f=open("file_name","r+")
a=f.readlines()
for line in f:
   if line.startswith("rai"):
      p=a.index(line)
#so now we have the position of the line which to be modified
a[p]="modification is done"
f.seek(0)
f.truncate() #ersing all data from the file
f.close()
#so now we have an empty file and we will write the modified content now in the file
o=open("file_name","w")
for i in a:
   o.write(i)
o.close()
#now the modification is done in the file
```

Answer (score 0):

writing initial data, print an empty `str` for updating it to a new data
here we insert an empty `str` in the last line of the code, this code can be used in interative updation, in other words appending data in text`.txt` file

```
with open("data.txt", 'w') as f:
    f.write('first line\n'
            'second line\n'
            'third line\n'
            'fourth line\n'
            ' \n')
```

updating data in the last line of the text file

```
my_file=open('data.txt')
string_list = my_file.readlines()
string_list[-1] = "Edit the list of strings as desired\n"
my_file = open("data.txt", "w")
new_file_contents = "". join(string_list)
my_file. write(new_file_contents)
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same request, eventually ended up with Jinja templating. Change your text file to below, and a variable lastname, then you can render the template by passing `lastname='Meg'`, that's the most efficient and quickest way I can think of.

```
Dan 
{{ lastname }} 
Warrior 
500 
1 
0
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#read file lines and edit specific item

file=open("pythonmydemo.txt",'r')
a=file.readlines()
print(a[0][6:11])

a[0]=a[0][0:5]+' Ericsson\n'
print(a[0])

file=open("pythonmydemo.txt",'w')
file.writelines(a)
file.close()
print(a)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @ajay-jaiswal Please specify your question and provide a minimal reproducible example and any error messages you're getting. You posted the code but not the actual question.

Answer (score -2):

This is the easiest way to do this.

```
f = open("file.txt", "wt")
for line in f:
    f.write(line.replace('foo', 'bar'))
f.close()
```

I hope it will work for you.