# Failing to scrape web data with Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to fetch data from the front page table on https://icostats.com/. But something just isn't clicking.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Scrapers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://icostats.com")
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/span/span""").s()
posts = browser.find_element_by_class_name("tdPrimary-0-75")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

The errors I'm getting:

*

> C:\Python36\python.exe C:/.../PycharmProjects/PyQtPS/ICO_spyder.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:/.../PycharmProjects/PyQtPS/ICO_spyder.py", line 5, in 
>       browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]""").click()
>   File
>   "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 313, in find_element_by_xpath
>       return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 791, in find_element
>       'value': value})['value']   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py",
>   line 256, in execute
>       self.error_handler.check_response(response)   File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py",
>   line 194, in check_response
>       raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such
>   element: Unable to locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]"}
>   (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.115)   (Driver info:
>   chromedriver=2.30.477700
>   (0057494ad8732195794a7b32078424f92a5fce41),platform=Windows NT
>   6.1.7600 x86_64)

*

**EDIT**

Finally got it working:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Scrapers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://icostats.com")
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#app > div > div.container-0-16 > div.table-0-20 > div.tbody-0-21 > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(8)")))

posts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("thName-0-55")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)

posts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tdName-0-73")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

Is there any way to iterate over every header/column and export it to a csv file without having to go through each class like this?

Comment: from the site i can see there is no other div inside the div with id app? so how are you trying? and what are you trying?

Comment: This, obviously, is related with `xpath`, are you sure the website's HTML structure contains those elements?

Comment: Yes, I also copied the xpath right out of Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required data generated dynamically by `JavaScript`. You need to wait until it present on the page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Scrapers\chromedriver.exe')
browser.get("https://icostats.com")
wait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#app>div")))
posts = browser.find_element_by_class_name("tdPrimary-0-75")
for post in posts:
    print(post.text)
```

Comment: This works great! Is there a way to run over every colum and fech headers and data to a, say, CSV file?

Comment: You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32248510/write-to-csv-python-horizontally-append-each-time?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

Answer (score 1):

1. Seems like there is no `s() method` in this line

> browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/span/span""").s()

so, what you need might be

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="app"]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[8]/span/span""").text
```

2. Since you want to iterate on the results, this line:

   `posts = browser.find_element_by_class_name("tdPrimary-0-75")`

should be

```
posts = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("tdPrimary-0-75")
```