# Python arranging a list and writing it back to file

Tags: python

I am trying to make a script which finds everything between a symbol {} in a text document. It takes the .txt documents specific part in the {} and organizes it alphabetically, then writing it inplace back to the text document.  Example of text document..

```
bla bla bla 
bla ba bl bla ba bl {apple:banana, this: something else, airplane:hobby}
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla
```

Desired output(sorted alphabetically)..

```
bla bla bla 
bla ba bl bla ba bl {airplane:hobby, apple:banana, this: something else}
bla bla bla 
bla bla bla
```

What its still printing..

```
    bla bla bla 
    bla ba bl bla ba bl {apple:banana, this: something else, airplane:hobby}
    bla bla bla 
    bla bla bla
```

My code..

```
def openFind():
    f = open(inFile, 'r')
    lines = f.read()
    match = re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', lines)
    before = str(match)
    n=1
    for i in xrange(0, len(match), n):
        mydict =  match[i:i+n]
        for x in sorted(mydict):
            c = x.split(',')
            newmatch = sorted(c)
            final =  str(newmatch)
            print final

            # NOT WORKING BELOW!!! Stuck in loop?
            with open(outFile,'w') as new_file:
                with open(inFile) as old_file:
                    for line in old_file:
                        new_file.write(line.replace(before, after))
```

It prints the sorted/alphabetical list as [airplane:hobby, apple:banana, this: something else], but how do I get it to replace the original text in the text document? Has to be inplace, but can make a new txt.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python)

Comment: Ive tried the fileinput function and it drastically changes my text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
import re

def openFind():
    with open("test.txt", "r") as in_file:
        data = in_file.read()

    def sub(m):
        l = [s.strip() for s in m.group(1).split(",")]
        l.sort()
        return "{%s}" % (", ".join(l),)

    replacement = re.sub(r'{(.*?)}', sub, data)
    with open("out.txt", "w") as out_file:
        out_file.write(replacement)
```

I have used [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) in order to replace with the sorted match in-place.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will sort items between `{` & `}` and write the result to same file:

```
import re

with open('test.txt', 'r+') as f:
    s = f.read()
    r = list(s)
    for mo in re.finditer('{(.*?)}', s):
        d = sorted(mo.group(1).split(', '))
        r[mo.start(1):mo.end(1)] = list(', '.join(d))

    f.seek(0)
    f.write(''.join(r))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this problem in pieces. First, you want to be able to read from one file and write to a new file. You could do this a multitude of ways. If your file is small you can just use `readlines()`, truncate your original file, and then write it back out.

But I'm going to assume the possibility of *huge* files (i.e. larger than will easily fit in RAM/swap space. Currently several GB in size).

```
import os
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False) as temp:
    with open(filename) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            temp.write(line)
    os.unlink(infile)
    os.rename(temp.name, infile.name)
```

Now we're reading each line and writing it out to the destination. Now all you need to do is intercept the line and change it up if that's necessary:

```
 for line in infile:
     match = re.search('{{.*?}}')
     if match:
          # Assumes you only have one "dictionary" per line
          first_part, rest = line.split('{', maxsplit=1)
          # allows for trailing data
          data, last_part = rest.split('}', maxsplit=1)
          data = [_.split(':') for _ in data.split(',')]
          data.sort()
          line = '{}{{{}}}{}'.format(first_part, ', '.join(':'.join(_) for _ in data))
     temp.write(line)
```

You might have to tweak with the exact algorithm, but that's the approach that I would take when confronted with a problem like this.

Answer (score 1):

The entire program can be written succinctly as follows,

```
with open("file.txt") as fr:
    content = fr.read()

matches = (match.group(1) for match in re.finditer(r"{(.*?)}", content))
for match in matches:
    repl = ", ".join(sorted(match.split(", ")))
    content = content.replace(match, repl)

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    fw.write(content)
```