# Python - replace a line by its column in file

Tags: python, file

Sorry for posting such an easy question, but i couldn't find an answer on google.
I wish my code to do something like this
code:

```
lines = open("Bal.txt").write
lines[1] = new_value
lines.close()
```

p.s i wish to replace the line in a file with a value

Comment: When you say replace a line by _its_ column, are you referring to some arbitrary character-column in a file, or some column based on a certain delimiter, or something else? It would be helpful to get some clarification on that point to be able to give a useful answer to your question.

As for the replacing a line part, here's a thread explaining that sub-question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python. I can't fit the code snippet in a comment, but essentially, you need to replace the line of the file, then re-write the whole file.

Comment: By column, i mean its position in the file. where lines[1] would be the first line located in the text file

Comment: Apologies for what would seem like a silly question to you as I haven't quite caught on - in your code snippet, is new_value simply any arbitrary text from somewhere else that you want to be the new text for row 1 in your 'Bal.txt'?

Comment: new_value is a variable

Comment: If new_value is a string I think the above link may apply:
`with open('Bal.txt', 'r') as file: data = file.readlines(); data[1] = new_value
 with open('Bal.txt', 'w') as file: file.writelines( data )`

(Can't format code snippets in comments unfortunately)

Comment: Do you mean row as opposed to column?

Answer (score 0):

xxx.dat before:

```
ddddddddddddddddd
EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
fffffffffffffffff

with open('xxx.txt','r') as f:
    x=f.readlines()
x[1] = "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ\n"
with open('xxx.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(x)
```

xxx.dat after:

```
ddddddddddddddddd
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ
fffffffffffffffff
```

Note:f.read() returns a string, whereas f.readlines() returns a list, enabling you to replace an occurrence within that list.
Inclusion of the `\n` (Linux) newline character is important to separate line[1] from line[2] when you next read the file, or you would end up with:

```
ddddddddddddddddd
QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQfffffffffffffffff
```