# Easy way to set on_delete across entire application

Tags: regex, django

I've been using the `-Wd` argument for Python and discovered *tons* of changes I need to make in order to prepare my upgrade to Django 2.0

```
python -Wd manage.py runserver
```

The main thing is that [`on_delete`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete) is due to become a required argument.

> RemovedInDjango20Warning: on_delete will be a required arg for ForeignKey in Django 2.0. Set it to `models.CASCADE` on models and in existing migrations if you want to maintain the current default behavior.
>
> See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Is there an easy regex (or way) I can use to put `on_delete` into all of my foreign keys?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Use with care

You can use

```
(ForeignKey|OneToOneField)\(((?:(?!on_delete|ForeignKey|OneToOneField)[^\)])*)\)
```

This will search for all foreign keys that currently do not already define what happens upon deletion and also ignores anywhere you have overridden ForeignKey.

It will then capture anything inside the brackets which allows you to replace the inner text with the capture group plus the on_delete

```
$1($2, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

It is not advised to do a replace all with the above, and you should still step through to ensure no issues are created (such as any pep8 line length warnings)

Comment: This was helpful, thanks. Note it doesn't match multi-line expressions.

Comment: Also worth noting that this will erroneously catch `GenericForeignKey` which does not have an `on_delete`. Also, `GenericForeignKey` is often instantiated without any arguments, thus this regex will change these lines to `foo = GenericForeignKey(, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` which in invalid Python. Regardless, this was a huge time-saver. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had to do this, and Sayse 's solution worked:

```
import re
import fileinput

import os, fnmatch
import glob
from pathlib import Path


# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571281/easy-way-to-set-on-delete-across-entire-application
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11898998/how-can-i-write-a-regex-which-matches-non-greedy
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/4719629/433570
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/2186565/433570

regex = r'(.*?)(ForeignKey|OneToOneField)\(((?:(?!on_delete|ForeignKey|OneToOneField)[^\)])*)\)(.*)'

index = 0
for filename in Path('apps').glob('**/migrations/*.py'):
    print(filename)
=>  filename = (os.fspath(filename), ) # 3.6 doesn't have this

    for line in fileinput.FileInput(filename, inplace=1):
        a = re.search(regex, line)
        if a:
            print('{}{}({}, on_delete=models.CASCADE){}'.format(a.group(1), a.group(2), a.group(3), a.group(4)))
        else:
            print(line, end='')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! I have adapted the script and the regex to work on multi-line (linted) migration files: https://gist.github.com/benjaoming/3e5770ffcf029c1e11d9a7f79f2e7f89

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly. Cases like these will fail because of ')' in the middle of line. `ForeignKey(..., related_name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_user")`

Answer (score 0):

I made this bash script that may help you.

```
#!/bin/bash
FK=()
IFS=$'\n'
count=0
for fk in $(cat $1 | egrep -i --color -o 'models\.ForeignKey\((.*?)');
do
    FK[$count]=$fk
    #FK+=$fk
    count=$(($count + 1))
done

for c in "${FK[@]}"; 
do 
    r=`echo "${c}" | sed -e 's/)$/,on_delete=models.CASCADE)/g'`
    a="${c}"
    sed -i "s/${c}/${r}/g" $1
done
```

Maybe you want a more "save" approach, changing `sed -i` with `sed -e` and redirect the output to a file to compare against your original models.py file.

Happy coding!!