# i'm saving data from a txt box to a specific line in a file but instead it saves on the first line

Tags: python, python-3.4

**PYTHON 3.4** 
i want to save to line 21 but it instead saves to line 1 same for when i save to line 22

```
 if event == 'Event 1' and indivcombo == 'Individual 1': 
        with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r+') as f:
            for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):         
                if i == 21:
                    individualmain = individual.get() 
                    f.writelines(individualmain)
                    f.writelines("\n")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing specific line in text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python)

Comment: no he is asking to swap out data in a file by using specific things in the file where im choosing specific lines and saving on to them so........ plus i likely just made a mistake and can't spot it as this should work as i did this before and it worked.

Comment: help don't hate

Comment: See this answer to the same question (Method 1 part): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39676548/5371551

Comment: that is what im doing but its not working see my problem???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you are closing and reopening the file after calculating `get_all`, and that you have a `else` to write the remaining lines

```
with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r+') as f:
    get_all=f.readlines()
with open("data/tournamentdatae1.txt",'r+') as f:
    for i,line in enumerate(get_all,1):      
        if i == 21:
            individualmain = individual.get() 
            f.writelines(individualmain)
            f.writelines("\n")
        else:
            f.writelines(line)
```