# How do I overwrite a specific line in a CSV file with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I'm making a program that lets you input data into a CSV file and then let you search for specific customers, and delete specific customers from the system. I've done the viewing part but I can't figure out how to overwrite a specific line in the csv file. This is what I have so far:

```
    choice = str(input("What would you like to do?"))
    if choice.lower() == "delete":
        Type = str(input("Type in 'Phone' to delete by Phone number and 'Name' to delete by Surnames: "))
        if Type.lower() == "phone":
            view = str(input("Enter the phone number of the customer you want to delete: "))
            check = csv.reader(open('D:\Programming\School Work\Johns Decorating company program\Customers.csv', "rt"), delimiter=",")
            for line in check:
                if view in line:
                    print(line)
                    confirm = str(input("Type 'Yes' to delete all of the quotes above. Type 'No' to restart or to select in a different way"))
                    if confirm.lower() == "yes":
                        #!THIS IS WHERE I'M CONFUSED!
                    elif confirm.lower() == "no":
                        print("Restarting search")
                        existing()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing specific line in text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python)

Comment: usr2564301, That's with a text file, I need to do it with a csv.

Comment: A csv *is* a text file.

Comment: @usr2564301 CSV is a string-representation of a table and is commonly stored as text in a fileobject or retrieved from databases. It is not per sei a text file.

Comment: @usr2564301 But that is exactly what I wrote, not you. Check the texts again. Nvm though. IT is not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform csv to a list and write:

```
for i in range(len(check)):
  if check[i][column_index] == phone_number:  # column_index is index
                                              # of a column where the phone numbers are stored
   del csv_list[i]
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: would that save the delete to the csv file?

Comment: That only deletes a row from the file. Then you can save the file as csv and then it will be saved.