# Using dict keys to find a matching line in a file, and once found, appending the corresponding values in the file

Tags: python

I have a dict with a few {key, value} pairs. I also have a file with some content.

The file is something like this:

```
some random text

...

...

text-which-matches-a-key

some important lines

...

...

some other important text until end of file
```

What I want is, to search/iterate through the file until a line matches a key of the dict, the append the corresponding value before/after `some important lines`

What I've tried to do is this:

```
with open('file', 'a+') as f:
    for key in a:
        if f.readlines() == key:
            f.writelines(a[key])
f.close()
```

where a is a dict, with many key,value pairs.

I'd be happy if the results are something like:

```
some random text

...

...

text-which-matches-a-key

some important lines

value corresponding to the key

...

...

some other important text until end of file
```

or:

```
some random text

...

...

text-which-matches-a-key

value corresponding to the key

some important lines

...

...

some other important text until end of file
```

Any help is appreciated.

P.S: Using Python 2.7, on PyCharm, on Windows 10.

Comment: As my answer to your previous question was the only one which returned your requested data as a dict, I assume you liked it and use it now for your task. In such cases I'd appreciate at least some "thanks" or an upvote instead of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few things mentioned here, and tinkering around with files and dictionaries, I finally came up with this snippet that works for me:

```
with open("input") as f:
    data_file = f.read()
f.close()
data = data_file.splitlines()
f = open('output', 'w')
for line in data:
    if line.strip() in b.keys():
        line = line.strip() + '\n' + b[line.strip()].rstrip() + '\n'
        f.writelines(line)
    else:
        f.writelines(line + '\n')
f.close()
```

where `data` is the content of the original file, and `b` is my dictionary of keys and values.

I don't know if answering my own question is allowed or not, but it got me the right output, hence posting it anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The script below can not insert multiple dictionary values. The value of the last dictionary key that appears before 'some important lines' in the file is inserted.

```
dictionary = {'text-which-matches-a-key': 'value corresponding to the key'}

# Open file and fill a list in which each element is a line.
f = open('file', 'r')
lines = f.readlines()
f.close()

# Empty the file.
f = open('file', 'w')
f.close()

# Insert dictionary value at the right place.
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    '''Remove the newline character '\n'
    to the right of the strings in the file.
    The lines don't match dictionary keys if
    the dictionary keys don't have newlines
    appended.'''
    line = line.rstrip()
    # Check if any line is a key in the dictionary.
    if line in dictionary.keys():
        key_occurs_in_text = True
        key_occurring_in_text = line
    ''' 'some important lines' is reached and a key
    of the dictionary has appeared as a line in the
    file. Save the list index which corresponds to
    the line after or before 'some important lines' in
    the variable insert_index. '''
    if 'some important lines' == line and key_occurs_in_text:
        insert_index = index + 1
        # insert_index = index - 1

'''A line in the file
is a key in the dictionary.
Insert the value of the key at the index we saved
in insert_index.
Prepend and append newline characters to match
the file format.'''
if key_occurs_in_text:
    lines.insert(insert_index, '\n'+dictionary[key_occurring_in_text]+'\n')

# Write the changed file content to the empty file.
f = open('file', 'w')
for line in lines:
    f.write(line)
f.close
```

Comment: I used your script, with a slight change, while iterating over the dict that i have. It worked with one slight difference. The text I need added is added at the start of the file. I tried to debug, with no result. Can you check that? The code I'd modified is adding `for i in b:
    dictionary = {i: b[i]}` at the start of the script

Comment: Also, getting this:`NameError: name 'key_occurring_in_text' is not defined`

Comment: Can you upload the script with your modifications and the text file you want to modify to github? Then I can examine why the text is added at the start of the file.
I tested the script with the text file you provide in your question. You can clone it from [github](https://github.com/michaelhochleitner/insert_dict_value) and test it. Using the file in the repository as input, the text is inserted at the right place.

Comment: Thanks for the offer, but I tinkered around with dicts and files and got the output I required.

Answer (score 2):

Your second version, i.e. inserting directly after the key line is quite simple.
If you don't mind loading the whole file into memory it's just

```
with open('file', 'r') as f:
    txt = f.readlines()

with open('file', 'w') as f:
    for line in txt:
        f.write(line)
        if line.strip() in block:
            f.write(block[line.strip()])
```

with `block` being your dictionary.

However, if you do not want to load the whole file at once, you have to write to a different file than your source file, because inserting into files (in opposite to overwriting portions of a file) is not possible:

```
with open('source_file', 'r') as fs, open(target_file,'w') as ft:
    for line in fs:
        ft.write(line)
        if line.strip() in block:
            ft.write(block[line.strip()])
```

Of course it would be possible to e.g. rename the source file first and then write everything to the original filename.

---

Regarding the first version, i.e. leaving several important lines after the key and insert the block after these lines, well,  that would require a proper definition of how to decide which or how many lines are important.

However, if it's just about a fix number of lines `N` after the key line:

```
with open(file, 'r') as f:
    txt = f.readlines()

with open(file, 'w') as f:
    N = 3
    i = -1
    for line in txt:
        f.write(line)
        if i == N:
            f.write(block[key])
            i = -1
        if line.strip()in block:
            key = line.strip()
            i = 0
        if i >= 0:
            i += 1
```

... or without loading all at once into memory:

```
with open('source_file', 'r') as fs, open(target_file,'w') as ft:
    N = 3
    i = -1
    for line in fs:
        ft.write(line)
        if i == N:
            ft.write(block[key])
            i = -1
        if line.strip()in block:
            key = line.strip()
            i = 0
        if i >= 0:
            i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

1. There's a difference between `readline()` and `readlines()` (the former reads 1 line, the latter reads all lines and returns a list of strings).
   See: https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/inputoutput.html
2. It'd be easier to just read the entire file, apply your changes to it, and write it back to a file once you're done, rather than trying to edit the file inplace.
   See: [Editing specific line in text file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4719438/editing-specific-line-in-text-file-in-python)
3. You don't have to manually close the file when you're useing the `with`-statement. The file will automatically close when you leave the `with`-block.

Answer (score 0):

`a+` means read and append, what you want is `r+` which writes a new line at the cursor location.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import fileinput

file = fileinput.FileInput(your_text_file, inplace=True)
for line in file:
    for key, value in yourdictionary.iteritems():
        line.replace(key, key + '\n' + value)
file.close()
```

Comment: AttributeError: FileInput instance has no attribute '__exit__'

Comment: Sorry! I edited the answer based on your interpreter version.

Comment: This isn't writing anything to the file.