# Python: How do I insert a string into a specific spot in a .txt file?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file with a variable called `id=`

How can I write a script that will look into that `.txt` file, find `id=` and insert a string right after the `=`?

I do have a separate `.py` file called dictionary that contains a dictionary with the purpose of finding and replacing certain words in the `.txt` file.

Could I also use this dictionary as a way to find and insert?

Comment: Short answer: You need to read the entire file again, insert the new data when you parse "id=" and then write the file again.

Comment: It is not good idea to name python module as dictionary.py

Comment: see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58378296/10197418)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the file line by line,  if line has 'id=' replace it with the builtin replace method of str and write the new line, else write the old line.

```py
with open(path_to_file) as fp:
  with open(path_to_new_file, 'w') as nfp:
    string = "whatever"
      for line in fp: 
        if "id=" in line:
          new_line = line.replace("id=", f"id={string}")
          print(f"replacing {line} with {new_line}")
          nfp.write(new_line)
        else: 
          nfp.write(line)
```