# Refactoring import statements across a repository

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a relatively big repo (too big for me to do the task manually) that needs a simple refactoring at every file.

I want to iterate over all files in my repo and replace statements like:

`from <old_location> import <something>`
to
`from <new_location> import <something>`

I have written the following code

```
import os


def refactor_imports(rootdir=PATH):
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            process_file(os.path.join(subdir, file))


def process_file(path):
    with open(path, 'a') as f_obj:
        for line in f_obj:
            if not line.startswith("from"):
                return

            else:
                #TODO: rewrite the line
```

and I am not sure how to complete it, how can you rewrite the file?
Is there a way to do so without reading the entire file content in memory?

Comment: load the file[s] into string and use `replace`

Comment: @balderman can it be done in a different way?

Comment: Why you want to do it in a different way?

Comment: Perhaps you could write a new file, line by line, and then move it into the old one, replacing it. That way you avoid reading all the file at once or storing it incrementally into a variable

Comment: how big are your files? can they fit into the memory individually? if so you can read them one by one and replace. if not, read the file line by line and write line by line to an another file and rename the file

Comment: Though I'd guess the files aren't big enough to be a problem reading one by one into memory. You tell us, however

Comment: assuming I go with reading the entire file, I should change the file mode to write and after replacing everything I need I just write it to the same file object?

Comment: Is that case, I believe you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4719562/12818877).